# Check if time is between two times

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to do the following in SQL :

I have three shifts:

> Shift 1 :  07:00 - 14:59
>  Shift 2:   15:00 - 22:59
>  Shift 3:   23:00 -
>   06:59

I want to know which shift i am actually in, depending on my sysdate (time).
The following statement doesn't work for "02:00". 
start_time and end_time are varchar2

```
 SELECT *  FROM abc
    WHERE to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') 
    between start_time and end_time;
```

How can i do that?

Comment: if start_time and end_time is in varchar, then what is the format of that date???

Comment: it's HH24:MI : Shift 1 : 07:00 - 14:59
Shift 2: 15:00 - 22:59
Shift 3: 23:00 - 06:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
  from abc
  where mod(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP))+1,24)
between mod(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(to_date(start_time,'hh24:mi') AS TIMESTAMP))+1,24)
    and mod(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(to_date(end_time,'hh24:mi') AS TIMESTAMP))+1,24)
```

;

Comment: YES ! You got it. Perfect. Thanks a lot !!